# joining 3 tables for a query

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access-2013

I am having an issue with my query, I've looked into it but it looks correct to me.

So I have 3 tables with the following fields.

```
Game
GameID, GameName, GenreID, ConsoleID

Genre
GenreID, GenreName

Console
ConsoleID, ConsoleName
```

This is the query I have written.

```
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;

string update = "SELECT Game.GameID, Game.GameName, Genre.GenreName, Console.ConsoleName "+
                "FROM Game "+
                "INNER JOIN Genre ON Game.GenreID=Genre.GenreID "+
                "INNER JOIN Console ON Game.ConsoleID=Console.ConsoleID";
command.CommandText = update;
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
DGV_searchResults.DataSource = dt;

connection.Close();
```

It works if i try to just use 2 tables, but getting 3 to work keeps throwing errors. 
Any ideas?

EDIT
[this is the error!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUdT2.png)

SOLUTION

```
string update = "SELECT Game.GameID, Game.GameName, Genre.GenreName, Console.ConsoleName 
FROM ((Game INNER JOIN Genre ON Game.GenreID=Genre.GenreID) 
INNER JOIN Console ON Game.ConsoleID=Console.ConsoleID)";
```

It needs parenthesis as access can only join one table at a time.
thanks all for the suggestions and help

Comment: please post the error which you get?

Comment: What is the error _exactly_?

Comment: Why have you named your query "update"?

Comment: if you run that query in SQL Server Management Studio, do you get an error? What is the error exactly?

Comment: The error says `Console.ConsoleI` instead of `Console.ConsoleID`

Comment: I wasn't sure why the error said that. I tried adding / removing spaces but to no avail

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: Ms Access 2013 and vs2010

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003048/ms-access-multi-join-query

Answer (score 0):

Even though your string variable name is called "update" when it is doing a sql-select query is no big deal, but apparently confused someone else.  Now, for dealing with extra spaces (or lack thereof), sometimes I find it better to do literal strings by using the "@" so cr/lf are intact and can also show easier readability... something like

```
string update = 
@"SELECT 
        Game.GameID, 
        Game.GameName, 
        Genre.GenreName, 
        Console.ConsoleName 
     FROM 
        Game 
           INNER JOIN Genre 
              ON Game.GenreID = Genre.GenreID 
           INNER JOIN Console 
              ON Game.ConsoleID = Console.ConsoleID ";
```

So now, there is no confusion of extra space or not within query... and all your original table/alias references were proper Case reference so you should not have any invalid alias references.

I have also encountered issues of somehow bad string content compiled even though what you type within quotes looks correct.  The only way to fix that was by removing all the

```
   "part "+ 
   "part2 " + 
   "part3 "
```

was to remove all the concatenated strings back into a single line like

```
"part part2 part3"
```

then recompile...  But maybe the literal string (via "@") will also fix it.

Comment: Its still throwing the same error. the tables are written correctly as I have done the query with just game and genre, as well as game and console tables by themselves and they display in datagrid fine. just when using all 3 tables it errors

Comment: @Kaertserif,  for grins, have you tried removing all the + segments and put into a single string (all on one line and not practical for reading, but I have seen that happen).  If so, is it still confused about "ConsoleI" vs "ConsoleID???"  Check the table structure to confirm?  Also is it an "I" like "ID" or "L" like "L"etter in the table structure.  I know we both believe it should be "ID", but who knows.

Comment: @Kaertserif, but what about the column names... is it really "I" vs  "ID" vs "LD"... Can you optionally remove the Genre table (and column reference) and see if it works on game + Console tables only?  And maybe worse yet, query just the Console table to see what it really has?

Comment: turns out access only supports one table join kinda. So i needed to add parenthesis to add the tables one by one. thanks for all your help tho

Comment: @Kaertserif, that does not sound right at all, and also, for future, edit your question to include "Access" as one of the tags.  SQL is too generic and can imply so many engines.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Game.GameID, Game.GameName, Genre.GenreName, Console.ConsoleName 
FROM Game 
    INNER JOIN Genre ON Game.GenreID=Genre.GenreID 
    INNER JOIN Console ON Game.ConsoleID=Console.ConsoleID;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Explain why your code should work.